Error when creating a custom blot in react quill editor
I'm trying to create a custom quote so I can format the html as desired
import styled from '@emotion/styled'
import CloseIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Close'
import {
  Box,
  Button,
  Chip,
  debounce,
  Dialog,
  DialogTitle,
  FormControl,
  Grid,
  IconButton,
  Stack,
  TextField,
  Typography,
} from '@mui/material'
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
import Parchment from 'parchment'
import Delta from 'quill-delta'
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { useController } from 'react-hook-form'
import ReactQuill, { ReactQuillProps } from 'react-quill'

import { storageService } from '@services'

import 'react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css'

interface QuillWrapperProps extends ReactQuillProps {
  forwardedRef: React.RefObject<ReactQuill>
}

const QuillNoSSRWrapper = dynamic(
  async () => {
    const Quill = (await import('quill')).default

    const BlockEmbed: any = Quill.import('blots/block/embed')

    class CustomBlockquoteBlot extends BlockEmbed {
 

      static create(value) {
        const node = super.create()
        node.setAttribute(
          'style',
          'background: #F4F4F6; border-radius: 8px; padding: 40px 32px; gap: 16px;'
        )
        node.innerHTML = `
          <p style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: 500; line-height: 32px; text-align: left; color: #00073D;">
            ${value.content}
          </p>
          ${
            value.title
              ? `<p style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: 700; line-height: 28px; text-align: left; color: #64668F;">出典: <strong>${value.title}</strong></p>`
              : ''
          }
          ${
            value.link
              ? `<p style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: 700; line-height: 28px; text-align: left; color: #64668F;">引用リンク: <a href="${value.link}" target="_blank" style="color: #64668F;">${value.link}</a></p>`
              : ''
          }
        `
        return node
      }

      static value(node) {
        const content = node.querySelector('p')?.innerHTML
        const titleElement = node.querySelector('strong')
        const linkElement = node.querySelector('a')

        return {
          content: content || '',
          title: titleElement ? titleElement.innerHTML : '',
          link: linkElement ? linkElement.href : '',
        }
      }
    }

    // Quill.register(CustomBlockquoteBlot)
    // Quill.register('blots/block/embed2', CustomBlockquoteBlot, true)
    // Quill.register('customBlockquote', CustomBlockquoteBlot)
    CustomBlockquoteBlot.blotName = 'customBlockquote'
    CustomBlockquoteBlot.tagName = 'blockquote'

    Quill.register('blots/customBlockquote', CustomBlockquoteBlot)

    console.log('quill.imports', Quill.imports)
    console.log('blotName:', CustomBlockquoteBlot.blotName)

    const { default: ReactQuill } = await import('react-quill')

    return ({ forwardedRef, ...props }: QuillWrapperProps) => (
      <ReactQuill ref={forwardedRef} {...props} />
    )
  },
  {
    ssr: false,
    loading: () => <p>Loading ...</p>,
  }
)

const CustomAdminQuillToolbar = ({ isLoading }: any) => (
  <ToolbarContainer
    id="toolbar"
    className="ql-toolbar ql-snow"
    style={{
      position: 'sticky',
      top: '28px',
      zIndex: 1000,
      backgroundColor: '#F4F4F6',
    }}
  >
    <button type="button" className="ql-header" value="2" style={{ width: 'fit-content' }}>
      H2
    </button>
    <button type="button" className="ql-header" value="3" style={{ width: 'fit-content' }}>
      H3
    </button>
    <button type="button" className="ql-header" value="4" style={{ width: 'fit-content' }}>
      H4
    </button>
    <button className="ql-bold" />
    <button className="ql-italic" />
    <button className="ql-underline" />
    <button className="ql-link" />
    <button className="ql-blockquote" style={{ padding: 0 }} />
    <button className={`ql-image ${isLoading ? 'disabled' : ''}`} disabled={isLoading} />
    <button className="ql-video" />
  </ToolbarContainer>
)

export const AdminEditorField = ({ name, control, ...props }: any) => {
  const {
    field,
    fieldState: { error },
  } = useController({ name, control })
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
  const [isQuoteModalOpen, setIsQuoteModalOpen] = useState(false)
  const [quoteContent, setQuoteContent] = useState('')
  const [quoteTitle, setQuoteTitle] = useState('')
  const [quoteLink, setQuoteLink] = useState('')
  const [cursorPosition, setCursorPosition] = useState<number | null>(null)

  const quillRef = useRef<any>(null)
  const isQuoteLinkEnabled = quoteTitle.trim().length > 0

  const handleUploadImage = useCallback(async () => {
    const input = document.createElement('input')
    input.setAttribute('type', 'file')
    input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*')
    input.click()

    input.onchange = async (e: any) => {
      if (e.target.files) {
        const file = e.target.files[0]
        setIsLoading(true)
        try {
          const downloadURL = await storageService.uploadFile(
            file,
            '/fortune/editor/image/' + file.name
          )
          setIsLoading(false)
          const quill = quillRef.current.getEditor()
          const range = quill.getSelection()?.index
          if (range !== null && range !== undefined) {
            quill.insertEmbed(range, 'image', downloadURL)
            quill.setSelection(range + 1)
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error uploading file:', error)
          setIsLoading(false)
        }
      }
    }
  }, [])

  const handleQuoteClick = useCallback(() => {
    const quill = quillRef.current.getEditor()
    const range = quill.getSelection()?.index

    if (range !== null && range !== undefined) {
      setCursorPosition(range)
    } else {
      setCursorPosition(null)
    }

    setIsQuoteModalOpen(true)
  }, [])

  const handleQuoteInsert = useCallback(() => {
    const quill = quillRef.current.getEditor()
    const range = cursorPosition !== null ? cursorPosition : quill.getSelection()?.index

    if (range !== null && range !== undefined) {
      const renderHTML = {
        content: quoteContent,
        title: quoteTitle,
        link: quoteLink,
      }
      console.log('quill.imports', quill)

      quill.insertEmbed(range, 'customBlockquote', renderHTML, 'user')

      quill.setSelection(range + 1)
      setIsQuoteModalOpen(false)
      setQuoteContent('')
      setQuoteTitle('')
      setQuoteLink('')
    }
  }, [quoteContent, quoteTitle, quoteLink, cursorPosition])
  // const handleQuoteInsert = useCallback(() => {
  //   const quill = quillRef.current.getEditor()
  //   const range = cursorPosition !== null ? cursorPosition : quill.getSelection()?.index
  //   console.log(' ~ handleQuoteInsert ~ range:', range)

  //   if (range !== null && range !== undefined) {
  //     const renderHTML = `
  //       <blockquote style="background: #F4F4F6; border-radius: 8px; padding: 40px 32px; gap: 16px;">
  //         <p style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: 500; line-height: 32px; text-align: left; color: #00073D;">
  //           ${quoteContent}
  //         </p>
  //         ${
  //           quoteTitle
  //             ? `<p style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: 700; line-height: 28px; text-align: left; color: #64668F;">
  //           出典: <strong>${quoteTitle}</strong></p>`
  //             : ''
  //         }
  //         ${
  //           quoteLink
  //             ? `<p style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: 700; line-height: 28px; text-align: left; color: #64668F;">
  //           引用リンク: <a href="${quoteLink}" target="_blank" style="color: #64668F;">${quoteLink}</a></p>`
  //             : ''
  //         }
  //       </blockquote>
  //     `

  //     quill.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML(range, renderHTML)
  //     quill.setSelection(range + 1)
  //     setIsQuoteModalOpen(false)
  //     setQuoteContent('')
  //     setQuoteTitle('')
  //     setQuoteLink('')
  //   }
  // }, [quoteContent, quoteTitle, quoteLink, cursorPosition])

  const modules = {
    toolbar: {
      container: '#toolbar',
      handlers: {
        image: handleUploadImage,
        blockquote: handleQuoteClick, // Sử dụng blockquote mặc định
        customBlockquote: handleQuoteClick, // Sử dụng custom blockquote blot
      },
    },
  }

  const formats = [
    'header',
    'bold',
    'italic',
    'underline',
    'link',
    'blockquote', // Blockquote mặc định
    'customBlockquote', // Custom blockquote blot
    'image',
    'video',
  ]

  const handleScroll = useRef(
    debounce(() => {
      const scrollY = window.scrollY
      const scrollX = window.scrollX
      window.sessionStorage.setItem('scrollPosition', JSON.stringify({ scrollX, scrollY }))
    }, 100)
  ).current

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)
  }, [handleScroll])

  useEffect(() => {
    const scrollPositionStr = window.sessionStorage.getItem('scrollPosition')
    if (scrollPositionStr) {
      const scrollPosition = JSON.parse(scrollPositionStr)
      if (scrollPosition) {
        window.scrollTo(scrollPosition.scrollX, scrollPosition.scrollY)
      }
    }
  }, [field.value])

  return (
    <FormControl
      error={Boolean(error)}
      style={{ width: props.style?.width, minHeight: props.style?.minHeight }}
    >
      <CustomAdminQuillToolbar isLoading={isLoading} />
      <QuillNoSSRWrapper
        forwardedRef={quillRef}
        theme="snow"
        modules={modules}
        formats={formats}
        {...field}
        {...props}
      />
      <CustomDialog open={isQuoteModalOpen} onClose={() => setIsQuoteModalOpen(false)} fullWidth>
        <Grid
          display="flex"
          justifyContent="space-between"
          alignItems="center"
          sx={{
            borderBottom: '1px solid #DBDBDB',
            padding: '12px',
          }}
        >
          <Box display="flex" justifyContent="space-between" alignItems="center">
            <IconButton onClick={() => setIsQuoteModalOpen(false)} sx={{ padding: '0 16px 0 0' }}>
              <CloseIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <CustomDialogTitle
              sx={{
                lineHeight: '14px',
                fontSize: '14px',
                fontWeight: '700',
                color: '#00073D',
              }}
            >
              引用
            </CustomDialogTitle>
          </Box>
          <Box>
            <CustomButton onClick={handleQuoteInsert}>適用</CustomButton>
          </Box>
        </Grid>
        <CustomDialogContent>
          <Grid>
            <Stack direction="row" alignItems="center" spacing={1}>
              <Typography variant="fs14" fontWeight={500} color={'#64668F'}>
                内容
              </Typography>
              <StyledChip label={'任意'} sx={{ bgcolor: '#64668F' }} />
            </Stack>
            <CustomTextField
              autoFocus
              margin="dense"
              fullWidth
              multiline
              rows={10}
              value={quoteContent}
              onChange={(e) => setQuoteContent(e.target.value)}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid>
            <Stack direction="row" alignItems="center" spacing={1}>
              <Typography variant="fs14" fontWeight={500} color={'#64668F'}>
                出典元タイトル文言
              </Typography>
              <StyledChip label={'任意'} sx={{ bgcolor: '#64668F' }} />
            </Stack>
            <CustomTextField
              margin="dense"
              fullWidth
              value={quoteTitle}
              onChange={(e) => setQuoteTitle(e.target.value)}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid>
            <Stack direction="row" alignItems="center" spacing={1}>
              <Typography
                variant="fs14"
                fontWeight={500}
                color={isQuoteLinkEnabled ? '#64668F' : '#999CB1'}
              >
                引用リンク
              </Typography>
              <StyledChip
                label={'任意'}
                sx={{ bgcolor: isQuoteLinkEnabled ? '#64668F' : '#999CB1' }}
              />
            </Stack>
            <CustomTextField
              margin="dense"
              fullWidth
              value={quoteLink}
              onChange={(e) => setQuoteLink(e.target.value)}
              placeholder="https://"
              disabled={!isQuoteLinkEnabled}
            />
          </Grid>
        </CustomDialogContent>
      </CustomDialog>
    </FormControl>
  )
}


When I run the function handleQuoteInsert to create a customBlockquote, I keep getting an error
Uncaught Error: [Parchment] Unable to create customBlockquote blot
Please help everyone, I thank you.
I want to be able to create a custom Block quote, so that when I enter data from the dialog, it will output a structure as I formatted it.
